# Flag overlay navigation broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, flags

I'm not sure how it's deciding which post to go to, but the flag overlay navigation arrows seem to no longer point to the previous/next flagged post

[image]

This is probably reproducible by going to a site with multiple open flags (I'm guessing [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/) might work) and trying to use the overlay from any flagged post; it seems to happen every time for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fix will be pushed out in the next build - thanks for finding it.